# JSONPath with filtering is not working properly in WSO2 ESB 5

Tags: json, jsonpath, wso2-esb

I have a below mentioned like JSONPayload and I want to select the JSON object having hotelcode `"ALE1_LON"` from the "content" array.

For this I have used `"$.content[?(@.hotelcode='ALE1_LON')]"` JSONPath expression as mentioned below in the property mediator.

```
    <property expression="json-eval($.content[?(@.hotelcode='ALE1_LON')])" name="hotelContet" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>$1</format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('hotelContet')"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <respond/>
```

Problem is, this returns an empty array.

But when I try same payload and same JSONPath with an [online JSONPath Tester](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/) it says my JSONPath is correct (sending below like JSON Object).

```
[  
   {  
      "hotelcode":"ALE1_LON",
      "hotelname":"Alexandra"
   }
]
```

- Why this is not working in WSO2 ESB Propery Mediator?
- Is this because of the JSONPath version?
- WSO2 is not supported this way?
- Do I need to iterate each element and filter?

**JSON Payload :**

```
{
    "_id":"INV27_1112",
    "_rev":"5-876038bf65752ce4505e50baea6d5581",
    "content":[
        {
            "hotelcode":"AMB3_LON",
            "hotelname":"Ambassadors Bloomsbury"
        },
        {
            "hotelcode":"ALE1_LON",
            "hotelname":"Alexandra"
        },
        {
            "hotelcode":"ALO_LON",
            "hotelname":"Aloft London Excel"
        }
    ]
}
```

- WSO2 ESB version : 5.0.0

**Note :**  `"json-eval($.content[0])"` like exprssions return results correctly

**References :**

- [WSO2 ESB refferred JSONPath article](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)
- [WSO2 ESB Doc on JSON Support](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/JSON+Support)

Answer (score 0):

Error is with the `json-eval` expression. `==` must be used for equality not =. eg : `json-eval($.content[?(@.hotelcode=='ALE1_LON')])` works fine. Thank you for the support.
Reference : https://odieweblog.wordpress.com/2015/09/20/new-json-path-expression-predicates/, http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2017/02/wso2-esb-with-javascript-object-notation.html